# Trouble with Javascript VAR

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing trouble with the code below. If I remove `var user_id` and `var company_id`, the javascript works correctly.

Why isn't this working?

```
var user_id = user_id;  
var company_id = company_id;


if (pageNum == 1)
    strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload.php?act=store&user_id=" + user_id;

else

    strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload.php?act=store&company_id" + company_id;

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(document.getElementsByName("ImageType").item(i).checked == true){
        strImageType  = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `var` statement declares a variable within the scope of the current function, shadowing any variables in higher-up scopes with the same name.

Your two lines of code in question are creating new variables `user_id` and `company_id` that completely hide the outside variables for the entire duration of this function, and then assigning them to themselves.

So you're setting each of those variables to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Jim, in fact i have moved variables on top, above funcion and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think their is no need to reassign user variables like `user_id` and `company_id`, they came from any where like from function which is called, so its enough to use

```
if (pageNum == 1)
    strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload.php?act=store&user_id=" + user_id;

else

    strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload.php?act=store&company_id" + company_id;

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(document.getElementsByName("ImageType").item(i).checked == true){
        strImageType  = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

without

```
var user_id = user_id;  
var company_id = company_id;
```